# How to add “Authenticated Users” into Security Filtering in GPO settings?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

How to add “Authenticated Users” into Security Filtering in GPO settings?
If I press Add and try to search for “Authenticated Users” nothing is found. I revomed “Authenticated Users” and now I want to get it back.

If I type "Authenticated Users" and press OK I get not found error.

Comment: you're not going to find it by browsing.  just type it in and click OK

Comment: That did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All servers use English versions. My RSAT tools are in English. "Authenticated Users" was in English. But...

I had to use the language which is used in my local desktop computer to add "Authenticated Users". English did not work!

Answer (score 0):

check this blog i got your problem check below link...

**Authenticated user part of domain user it will apply to all user if you not specific condition like link GPO on specific OU**

http://www.rebeladmin.com/2018/04/group-policy-security-filtering/